# Error while uploading file to PHP and displaying it using fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to get an image via form and display it in pdf using fpdf, I'm getting an error:

> Undefined index: foo in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\login.php on line 16

Here is my php code:

```
$target_dir = "PhpProject1/";

$tf = $target_dir.  basename($_FILES["foo"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($tf,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$pdf->Image( "$imageFileType", 50, 108, 110 );
```

here is my html code:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="foo" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="foo">
```

Comment: Provide html code inside of <form> tags please. Probably your input tag is outside of <form> tag.

Comment: it is inside <form> tag only my other form elements are displaying fine except for the image

Comment: @ShineA, as mertizci said. Post the whole html for the form, including the form. Not just the input. Also, show us the code from line 16.